# No se puede encontrar la información de esquema para el elemento 'log4net'

Tags: c#, log4j, app.config

Hola estoy implementando log4net para grabar logs en base de datos, pero no graba ningun dato, en la consola lista de errores (No son errores ni warning solo mensajes), me muestra, No se puede encontrar la información de esquema para el elemento xxxx 'log4net'. Salen 79 lineas de mensaje.

Creo que el app.config se encuentra bien... lo expongo para que lo examinen

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <configuration>
<configSections>
<section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"></section>
```

```
<!--Ajustar SQl al LOG4NET-->
<log4net>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=DocumentCedBD;integrated security=true" />
  <!--;persist security info=True;User ID=logUser;Password=logPassword-->
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO dbo.LogLectura (FechaHora, Usuario, Evento, Nivel, Registrador, Mensaje, Excepcion) VALUES (@log_date, @usuario, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@usuario" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
</appender>
 </log4net>
 </configuration>
```

y me puedan ayudar con la respuesta, **el buffersize es valor 1** asi que eso no es...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <log4net>
<root>
  <level value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
</root>
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <param name="File" value="C:\Test\Logs.txt" />
  <param name="appendToFile" value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <param name="conversionPattern" value="[%date] %level %thread %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
  <bufferSize value="1" />
  <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=3.5.30729.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <connectionString value="data source=xxx ;initial catalog=Pextran;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxx" />
  <commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception],[Method],[Ip],[Pagina],[IdUsuario]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception,@name_methods,@ip, @pagina, @id_usuario)" />
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_date" />
    <dbType value="DateTime" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@thread" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@log_level" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="50" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%level" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@logger" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@message" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="4000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%message" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@exception" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@name_methods" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="255" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{name_methods}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@ip" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="30" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{ip}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
   <parameterName value="@pagina" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{pagina}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>
  <parameter>
    <parameterName value="@id_usuario" />
    <dbType value="String" />
    <size value="2000" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%property{id_usuario}" />
    </layout>
  </parameter>

</appender>
<logger name="Test"></logger>
```

```
<configuration>
 <configSections>
   <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" />
</configSections>
```

Esta es mi configuración para log4net. Espero que te pueda servir. Me sirve para consola, archivo y base de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Assembly System.Data
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Data.dll

Comment: hola en ese caso debo cambiar la version del dll, system.Data??
Version=3.5.30729.1 A **Version=4.0.0.0** ????

Comment: Para la configuración que te he publicado tienes que trabajar con la versión 4.0. Ya que trabaje con el framework 4.0 de mi solucion

Comment: y la 4.5 saca problemas?? ya consulte la pagina de apache y no aparece con problemas [enlace]https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/framework-support.html ... ya cambie mi tabla coloque tu codigo pero ni con appender RollingFile saca problemas... no lee el app.config con los tag de <log4net>

Comment: Voy a levantar un proyecto con version 4.5 y te comento

Comment: Y como te ha ido con el tema. Por temas de tiempo no he podido realizar las pruebas.

Comment: Desistí usar log4net en framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

Intenta colocar esto en el `AssemblyInfo.cs` del proyecto.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch = true, ConfigFile = "App.config")]
```

Comment: ctm002 no aun asi no me Graba en la Base de Datos :s

Comment: Te adjunte la configuracion de mi proyecto. Espero que te sirva.

Comment: ademas si tengo esta linea    en el contructor de mi winform     
public FrmLectura()
        {

            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
creo que [assembly: XmlConfigurator(Watch =true, ConfigFile ="App.config")] Sobraria????